# Как в IDEA настроить интегрированный Git чтобы merge проходил с параметром --no-ff

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Возможно ли настроить параметры `merge` в интегрированном в IDEA Git, например, чтобы `merge` выполнялся с параметром `--no-ff`?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/merge-branches-dialog.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711541/howto-use-no-fast-forward-flag-when-merging-branches-in-git-with-idea/21731728
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Галочку поставьте в этом окне

Comment: спасибо, но эту галочку можно выбрать только если я выполняю VSC->Git->Merge Changes... а я делаю команду merge выбирая в idea в правом нижем углу Git:Master->merge

Comment: > а я делаю команду merge выбирая в idea в правом нижем углу
> Git:Master->merge Для такого случая пока никак. Голосуйте за задачу: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99115